# How to call AWS SSM API inside lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-ssm

I have a requirement, where I need to run a shell script inside my ec2 instance when the instance state changes from stopped to running.
I used cloud watch for this requirement but the event is trigerring the shell script when the instance is in pending state but not in running state(I have used "ec2 instance state-change notification" and "running" as parameter. Target as RunCommand).
Now I am trying to use SSM association I was succeded in trigerring the shell script manually but i need to automate it (i.e., when ec2 instance status changed to running only the bash script should start running)

Comment: Where does the lambda come into play?

Comment: I was trying different ways to run my script... one of the ways is with lambda

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is how to automatically execute a script with *every restart* of your EC2 instance (these options do not use AWS Systems Manager).

**Use user data scripts and cloud-init directives**

> By default, user data scripts and cloud-init directives run only
>   during the first boot cycle when an instance is launched. However, you
>   can configure your user data script and cloud-init directives with a
>   mime multi-part file. A mime multi-part file allows your script to
>   override how frequently user data is executed in the cloud-init
>   package. Then, the file executes the user script.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/

Alternatively, you can **execute a cron job after system reboot**, see more info here:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/